# Python pivot dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Please let me know if this is the wrong way of asking for help.

For e.g. I have the following DataFrame:

```
l1   l2   value
----------------
a     d     1000
b     e     2000 
c     f     4500    
c     e     500
d     a     200
```

I would like to create a pivot table/or pivot it such that both the rows and columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

```
columns    a    b    c    d     e    f
rows
a                        1000 
b                              2500
c                               500  4500
d         200
e
f
```

After which, sort both the rows & columns according to the value and plot as heatmap. 
I was only able to plot the heat map with rows = l1, columns = l2 (with the code below) and have been stuck for awhile

```
df = df.pivot(index='l1', columns='l2', values='value')
min= max(df['value'])
max = min(df['value'])
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, light=.5)
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap,vmin=min,  vmax=max,mask=df.isnull(),linewidths=.008)  
plt.show(
```

I've also attached a screenshot in excel for my desired output
[screenshot output in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMg4z.png)

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Editing to add explanation:**
I couldn't think of a better solution to be able to get the sums similar to your excel pivot_table. What I did is from the `df` dataframe, I created two pivot tables `df1`, `df2` switching the columns and the index. I then used `pd.concat`.pd.concat definition *Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic along the other axes.* to combine the two dataframes. Link here

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat

So if you run this `df_final = pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=0,sort=True)` instead of line 4, you will see that its just combined along the columns.

Then groupby is somewhat similar to pivot, *Group series using mapper (dict or key function, apply given function to group, return result as series) or by a series of columns.* Link here
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby

Since pd.concat produced 2 rows of each, groupby summed those rows together to produce the final dataframe

**Original**
There must be a better way to do this, but this method seems to work.
    df = pd.DataFrame({'l1':['a','b','c','c','d'],'l2':['d','e','f','e','a'],'value':[1000,2000,4500,500,200]})
    df1 = df.pivot_table(index='l2',columns='l1',values='value')
    df2 = df.pivot_table(index='l1',columns='l2',values='value')
    df_final = pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=0,sort=True).reset_index().groupby('index').sum()
    min = df['value'].max()
    max = df['value'].min()
    cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, light=.5)
    sns.heatmap(df_final, cmap=cmap,vmin=min,  vmax=max,mask=df_final.isnull(),linewidths=.008)

[image]

Comment: Hi! yes it works for my dataframe! thank you so much. May I ask for an explanation on this line : df_final = pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=0,sort=True).reset_index().groupby('index').sum().           In particular, 1) the .groupby('index') : what does it group the index by? and 2)what does the sum() does in this instance?

Comment: I've managed to plot the heat map in ordered sequence of both the df1 & df2 using part of the code from Mike's answer.

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Heat Map]

You have several little issues with your code, primarily that you really shouldn't override core variables like min/max! :)

Otherwise, you just needed to add a column sum and row sum variable to sort by and then drop it before you plot. If your dataframe is significantly bigger you can consider assigning the sums to an external variable and sort by it without assigning it to your dataframe to reduce processing time.

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('a', 'd', 1000),
    ('b', 'e', 2000),
    ('c', 'f', 4500),
    ('c', 'e', 500),
    ('d', 'a', 200)
], columns=['l1', 'l2', 'value'])
dfp = df.pivot(index='l1', columns='l2', values='value')
minv = max(df['value'])
maxv = min(df['value'])
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, light=.5)
dfp.loc[:, 'rowsum'] = dfp.sum(axis=1)
dfp.loc['colsum', :] = dfp.sum(axis=0)
dfp = (
    dfp
    .sort_values('rowsum', ascending=False, axis=0)
    .sort_values('colsum', ascending=False, axis=1)
    .drop('rowsum', axis=1)
    .drop('colsum', axis=0)
)
sns.heatmap(dfp, cmap=cmap,vmin=minv,  vmax=maxv,mask=dfp.isnull(),linewidths=.008)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi mike! I would like to have both L1 & L2 in the heat map to show  ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] rather than its original value